# Only one item displayed in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am debugging and I get the correct number of items from Server. And It also calls onCreateViewholder and onBindViewHolder as many as the item size.

However, my RecyclerView only show one item in the list.

And most of the problem after my search was when the height of RecyclerView is `match_parent`. Mine was `match_parent` as well. So, I changed it to `wrap_content`. But It gets correct the number of items and correct item data. But can't display the all the times in the Recycler view.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<MyData> MyDataArrayList;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView userId;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            Log.d(TAG, "created()");
            tvUserID = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_myitem);
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter (ArrayList<MyData> myDataArrayList) {
        Log.d(TAG, "new MyAdapter instance created");
        this.myDataArrayList = myDataArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder()");
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder()=\nposition: " + position + ",\nitem: " + myDataArrayList.get(position).toString());

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;

        Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount(): " + getItemCount());
        try {
            String username = myDataArrayList.get(position).getUser();
            myViewHolder.userId.setText(username);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myDataArrayList.size();
    }
}
```

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MyActivity.this);
myAdapter = new myAdapter(myDataArrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

this is `my_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_myitem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="username"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What's the prolbem of this?

Comment: have you tried to change the height to fixed size(in dp)?

Comment: @AntonMakov Yes, but didn't work.

Comment: recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

Please use this before setAdapter

Comment: I assume that you're forgetting to call `notifyDataChanged()` after adding more items into your `myAdapter`.

Comment: Post your `my_item.xml` layout code as well.

Comment: @VirajPatel I updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My_item.xml has width and height of matchparent ,change the height to wrap content.

Comment: And change recyclerview height as match parent.

Comment: I was so stupid... thanks. And I think for the Recyclerview the height must be `wrap_content` as far as I know.

Comment: If the root layout is the linear layout than use property of weight otherwise use match parent of fixed size to make sure that the minimum 2 to 3 rows are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `my_item.xml` file.
**You have to set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` instead of `android:layout_height="match_parent"`and it will work and display all items.**

In existing code, it is also adding all items but due to `match_parent` you are able to see only one item. If you scroll the `RecyclerView` then you will be able to see other items as well.

Also, you can keep `RecyclerView` height as `match_parent` as per your need.